# Laurent Series of $~\dfrac{ze^z}{z-1}~$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I've come across a problem that, the question is as follows.

Determine the Laurent Series of $~\dfrac{ze^z}{z-1}~$ about $~z=1~$.

I've tried to this in numerous different ways, but I can't seem to make much progress on it.

How would I get started on doing this problem? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd write $z=1+w$.

Comment: If you edited in what the "numerous different ways" you tried were, then I am sure this question would be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac{ze^z}{z-1}=e \cdot e^{z-1}(1+ \frac{1}{z-1}).$ Now invoke the power series of $e^{z-1}.$